# Why a video won't load if Source is set from another Window in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I had 2 mediaelements in one window, my program worked correctly asigning video to each mediaelement.

I created a second wpf window, a window I have access with no problem, I can set a Image Source and it works, I can change the selectedIndex of a TabControl and it works.

The problem is when I want to assign the source of a mediaelement. The Source property is assigned, but it never loads, `loaded` and `mediafailed` events never trigger, not matter if I assign the events in the xaml, in the cs of the first or the seccond Window.

When I use a button with a breakpoint on the first window to watch variables this is the result:

- `mediaelement.Source` is set correctly with the `URI` object.
- `mediaelement.IsLoaded` is `false`;
- Test flags I set in the `mediafailed` and `loaded` events never set.

This is what we know:

- The URI is not the problem because it works when the mediaelement is on the first window.
- I'm creating the second window from the first window.
- I can set Image.Source in the second window whit no problem, and `image.isLoaded` changes to `true`.
- I'm using Dispatcher.Invoke to set the values.
- If i use a `throw new NotImplementedException();` in the events it never throws.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just did an experiment. If I put the mediaelement in a tabcontrol tab, select another tab, set the Source value, change back to the tab where the mediaelement is, the `loaded` event fires correctly. If tab is visible from the begining it won't load. If tab remains hidden it won't load. It only loads when the tab is hidden and then shown.

Comment: You should supply sufficient code and markup to easily replicate your issue. I guess maybe your code is in the loaded event of something and it already loaded. When you change tabs whatever you change to will fire loaded.